# Running android app problem : E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: android, android-studio

I get the next message from logcat afyter trying to run my app in andorid studio:

5545-5545/com.example.reyesdelafter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.reyesdelafter, PID: 5545
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.reyesdelafter/com.example.reyesdelafter.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class cannot be instantiated
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class cannot be instantiated
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Also y get the message: "E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe" before that, my code is exactly the same as in the beginning (and it runned well in the emulator, but I do some tries to change the icons of bottom nav view, and some other things but I get back everything to normality (or so I thought ) and it does not run properly. What is the possible problem ? I alredy tried to uprgrade SDK tools, and make sure my Manifest.xml includes my main activity.

The app has just the splash screen and login with Firebase alredy well done and it runned well before that. Thanks

Comment: Is it okay if you post your MainActivity? Or if it is open source, a link to the Github project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)